# Full Attack Bonus With numerous attacks

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, barbarian

I have a Barbarian using the [Lesser Beast Totem](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/beast-totem-lesser-su). According to the effect:

> While raging, the barbarian gains two claw attacks. These attacks are considered primary attacks and are made at the barbarian’s full base attack bonus.

Does this mean that (at level 6) while raging, and I have a BAB of +6 / +1, I get 4 claw attacks , 2 with a +6, and 2 with a +1? Or can I only use my maximum value, and only take two? In addition, do I get to add my Strength Mod to my attack rolls, since they are Melee attacks?

Comment: +6/+1 at level 6 for a barbarian.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Natural weapons operate under different rules than do manufactured weapons, which are covered in the [Universal Monster Rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks) and in the [Combat Rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Natural-Attacks). The short version is, you get to attack once with each natural weapon, regardless of how many iterative attacks you have from high BAB.

So if your BAB was +6/+1, you would get to attack once with each claw, each at +6 BAB. Total of two attacks, not four, and you would never make the claw attacks (or any other attacks) at +1 BAB.

You could combine these natural attacks with manufactured weapons as long as they don’t use the same limb. For example, say your barbarian wore spiked armor: you could attack with both the spiked armor and the claws. When you do so, you take all your regular attacks from BAB with the manufactured weapon, and then *also* take any natural attacks you have, but treated as secondary. In this case, this would be spiked armor +6, spiked armor +1, claw +1, claw +1. That way you do get four attacks. Note that secondary natural attacks also add only half your Strength bonus to their damage.

Comment: And what happens once I reach 3 attacks? Do I spike with +11/+6/+1 and then claw with +1/+1?

Comment: @Flotolk If you used the spiked armor, then yes. If not, you'd just get claw +11, claw +11.

Comment: I added the link to Natural Attacks in the Combat rules, because the Universal Monster rules don't actually state that you don't get iteratives. Because with rules so oft misunderstood, having a single source would be far to simple, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MrLemon Yeah, I was tempted to close this as a duplicate but then didn't because I didn't want to have to go and figure out all the *other* duplicates of this question. Quite possibly the most frequently-asked question on the site.

Comment: @KRyan, wouldn't an 11th level attack be +11/+6/+1 on spiked armor, and then claw with +6/+6? Secondary natural attacks just get a flat -5, not "whatever your worst iterative is."

Comment: @PaulMarshall True, derp. Very good point.

Comment: @Flotolk See Paul Marshall's comment here: the +11 version would be spiked armor +11, spiked armor +6, spiked armor +1, claw +6, claw +6.

Comment: This is a spell/item. As such, its description should override the default rules. The description is explicit that you "*gain two claw attacks*" which are "*considered primary attacks*" at *full BAB* and damage is "1d6 points of slashing damage ... plus the barbarian’s Strength modifier." (not half strength) The item description does not state anything to the effect that you form claws and handle them according to the rules for natural weapons in the Uniform Monster Rules. While interpreting this with those is good, the claw attacks are *explicitly* primary (+6)/full strength bonus to damage.

Comment: @Makyen They are generally primary, yes. When you combine them with manufactured weapon attacks, however, *they are treated as secondary even though they are primary.* To avoid that, the *beast claws* rage power would have to explicitly *say* that it was overriding that rule. It does not.

Comment: @KRyan: I would agree with that if the description called them "Natural Attacks", which it *easily* could have done with less text than is currently in the item description. However, it does *not* state that they are natural attacks (never mentioned in the description). The description *very explicitly* states that "the barbarian *gains* two claw attacks" that they are "considered primary attacks", etc. Your interpretation assumes that the writer's intent was that they be treated as natural attacks when the writer(s) went out of their way to not use that term.

Comment: @Makyen Claw attacks are always natural attacks; it does not need to say that. Moreover, the phrase “primary attack” is used nowhere else in the rules, and can *only* be referring to natural attacks. You would have to demonstrate that effects that add natural weapons *usually* use the term natural attack, rather than allowing the type of natural attack to imply that. A quick search shows this is not the case, however; no creature labels their natural attacks as such, they just use the terms for specific kinds of natural attacks. That includes templates that add natural attacks.